Remove view-selection option from SharePoint List view web part command bar, but keep New button to add items
On modern SharePoint, I have a page with list web part showing a view of a list on that site. I would like users to be able to create new items using the 'New' button which shows with the command bar enabled. But that also allows user to go through the other views via selection menu that appears at the right side of the command bar.
I've tried JSON commands and seen code to hide/unhide the other elements of command bar (e.g'edit in grid view', 'Share', 'Export to Excel' etc), but haven't found what hides the view selector dropdown. Tried searching online and seems it may not be possible to remove that feature if command bar is enabled. Hoping someone here has an answer.


I have the same question!

You can keep one public view and the rest private.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-list-public-and-private-views/7dd2c29f-4eec-4aac-bcc9-b0aae9df5c0b
SharePoint doesn't let you manage permissions for views separate from list permissions.
